# JS Trigger Condition on Field Value Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByName("region").forEach(function(node) {
   node.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
});

function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("region") == "Ohio") {
        window.location = 'page3.html';
    }
    else {
        window.alert("Try again!");
    }  
    return false;
}
</script>
```

For each character I type in the field with name "region", the alert box shows up (so JS is firing). The input field also has id set to "region". But when I insert the value "Ohio", the alert box still fires up.

Can someone help on this please?

Comment: PS. put the code last, looks better in the summary when looking throught questions

Comment: 1st look .. `document.getElementById("region") == "Ohio"` should be `document.getElementById("region").value == "Ohio"`

Comment: I would have used the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) event instead of "keyup"...

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the value from the element like this.

```js
document.getElementsByName("region").forEach(function(node) {
   node.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
});

function myFunction() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("region").value);
    if (document.getElementById("region").value == "Ohio") {
        window.location = 'page3.html';
    }
    else {
        window.alert("Try again!");
    }  
    return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="region" name="region"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RenzoCC's answer, i would just add either toUpperCase or toLowerCase function on the if statement to cater for user case inputs.

```
    if (document.getElementById("region").value.toLowerCase() == "ohio") {
```